404 Occurrence Problems When Deploying a react project to Apache
If you build a small project that you made after learning the react for the first time, upload files and folders to the Apache server, and access them
Unexpected Application Error!
404 Not Found

It will be output.
The access address type is
http://Ipadress/userid

When first built, the main.js and main.css paths are
http://Ipadress/static/css 
http://IpIpadress/static/js 

I couldn't find the exact path because I was caught, so I created an .env file through a search
PUBLIC_URL = http://ip/userid

After you create it, rebuild it, and then go to the Olini path normally
The screen has the same error as the first one.
​What I tried searching is in the public_html folder
.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
Require all granted
</IfModule>

and created it for me
The apache setting is
<Directory "home/users/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    Options MuliViews SymLinkIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>

It is set to .
Additionally, I'm using reacr-route-dom, but it's not in the form of a page
There is no place to apply url because it is simply set as layout,
route.js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Head />,
    loader: ScheduleMainLoader,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <ScheduleMain />,
        //loader: ScheduleMainLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

App.jsx
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppProvider contexts={[CommonProvider, ModalProvider]}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AppProvider>
  );
};


Additionally, if you click index.html on the network, in the preview
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

It's being printed as above, but is it originally being printed?
Please give me some tips or know-how.

Does this answer your question? How to deploy a React App on Apache web server

Thank you for your reply.
The one from the link you posted is something I've already tried.

What is the structure of your build directory?

If it's a build directory
/home/users/scheduler/public_html
It is.
